# Is there a way to deduce a type of a single element of an array in c++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

I'm having problem with deducing a type of a single element of an c++ array.

I would like to do achieve something like:

```
template <class T>
struct array_element { };

template <class T>
struct array_element<T[]> {
   using type = T;
};

int main() {
   int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   array_element<decltype(a)>::type element = a[0];
}
```

But the code obviously does not compile (the int[5] does not match T[])...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need an extra argument for the specialization:

```
template <class T, size_t N>
struct array_element<T[N]> {
   using type = T;
};
```

---

Alternatively:

```
std::remove_reference<decltype(a[0])>::type element = a[0];
```

Or:

```
auto element = a[0];
```

Comment: Actual code is a bit more complex (is inside templates argument) and using the approach with `decltype` wouldn't be very clean there... But your suggestion with additional parameter of specialization suits perfectly!

Answer (score 13):

Use `std::remove_extent` template class (C++11) or `std::remove_extent_t` alias template (C++14) to get a type of an array element (both [are declared in `type_traits` header file](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_extent)):

```
std::remove_extent<decltype(a)>::type element0 = a[0];

std::remove_extent_t<decltype(a)> element1 = a[1];
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20c428a450de16af)

You can also use `std::remove_all_extents` (C++11) or `std::remove_all_extents_t` (C++14) to [get a type of an element of a multidimensional array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_all_extents).

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about this one!